# Rendering partial through modal in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Modal div in layout:

```
main
  = render 'layouts/desktop_sidebar'
  #modal-window.modal aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1"

  .main-content
    = render 'flash'
    = yield
```

Modal content:

```
.modal-dialog role="document"
  .modal-content
    .modal-header
      button.close aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"
        span aria-hidden="true"  &times;
      h4#myModalLabel.modal-title Modal title
    .modal-body
      | Test body content
    .modal-footer
      button.btn.btn-default data-dismiss="modal" type="button"  Close
      button.btn.btn-primary type="button"  Save changes`
```

Link to toggle modal:

```
= link_to 'Quick Add', companies_quick_add_path, remote: true, data: { toggle: "modal", target: '#modal-window' }
```

quick_add.js.erb

```
$("#modal-window").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'quick_add') %>");
```

Clients controller action:

```
def quick_add
    @client = Client.new
    initialize_client_children

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
end
```

DOM before clicking link:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu4ni.png)

DOM after clicking link:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeWVQ.png)

When clicking the link to render the modal, it hits the controller action and successfully reaches the view partial. The screen darkens, but the modal does not show at all.

When moving the modal out of the partial and placing the modal content right below the div and id declaration, the model will render, but I obviously have no access to the controller variables.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the `"#modal-window"` element? You should be selecting the `.modal-body`. Such as:

```
$(".modal-dialog .modal-body").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'quick_add') %>");
```

Comment: The #modal-window element is in my layout file.

This method works - you also select the modal-body as you suggested.

I simply had set layout to false in my controller respond_to block for js.